# horizontal line and right way to code it in html, css

Tags: html, css

I need to draw a horizontal line after some block, and I have three ways to do it:

1) Define a class `h_line` and add css features to it, like

```
#css
.hline { width:100%; height:1px; background: #fff }

#html
<div class="block_1">Lorem</div> <div class="h_line"></div>
```

2) Use `hr` tag

```
#css
hr { width:100%; height:1px; background: #fff }

#html
<div class="block_1">Lorem</div> <hr />
```

3) use it like a `after` pseudoclass

```
#css
.hline:after { width:100%; height:1px; background: #fff; content:"" }

#html
<div class="block_1 h_line">Lorem</div>
```

Which way is the most practical?

Comment: I would think the `<hr>` is the most semantic. I mean, isn't that what it's meant for?

Comment: why not use `border-bottom`?

Comment: In HTML5 the HTML <hr> element represents a thematic break between paragraph-level elements (for example, a change of scene in a story, or a shift of topic with a section).

Comment: Only use `<hr>` if the line semantically denotes a thematic break. Do _not_ use an `<hr>` if it's purely decorative; instead use a non-semantic element like a `<div>` and style it with CSS.

Answer (score 178, accepted):

```css
hr {
    display: block;
    height: 1px;
    border: 0;
    border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
    margin: 1em 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<div>Hello</div>
<hr/>
<div>World</div>
```

Here is how [html5boilerplate](http://html5boilerplate.com/) does it:

```
hr {
    display: block;
    height: 1px;
    border: 0;
    border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
    margin: 1em 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Comment: **Note:** Use `margin: 1em auto` if you want it to always be in the center of the page.

Comment: @JacquesMarais, not sure that's necessary as it is a block element with no defined width so it would span the width of the entire container anyway.

Answer (score 67):

I'd go for semantic markup, use an `<hr/>`.

Unless it's just a border what you want, then you can use a combination of padding, border and margin, to get the desired bound.

Comment: `<hr>` is valid HTML5. It used represent a horizontal rule, but is now defined in semantic terms as a thematic break between content. Most browsers will still display it as a horizontal line unless told otherwise.

Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/hr

Comment: Title says horizontal line and <hr/> is that so I up this. Title maybe should have read styled horizontal line.

Comment: @RyanBayne ... but but but ... hr = horizontal rule, not line :)

Answer (score 21):

```css
.line {
  width: 53px;
  height: 0;
  border: 1px solid #C4C4C4;
  margin: 3px;
  display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>
<div class="line"></div>
<div style="display:inline-block;">OR</div>
<div class="line"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You  have not answered the question "Which is the most practical?"

Answer (score 13):

> In HTML5, the `<hr>` tag defines a thematic break. In HTML 4.01, the
>   `<hr>` tag represents a horizontal rule.

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_hr.asp

So after definition, I would prefer `<hr>`

Answer (score 13):

If you really want a ***thematic break***, by all means use the `<hr>` tag.

---

If you just want a design line, you could use something like the css class

```
.hline-bottom {
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #000; /* whichever color you prefer */
}
```

and use it like

```
<div class="block_1 hline-bottom">Cheese</div>
```

Answer (score 6):

I wanted a long dash like line, so I used this.

```css
.dash{
        border: 1px solid red;
        width: 120px;
        height: 0px;

}
```

```html
<div class="dash"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

My simple solution is to style hr with css to have zero top & bottom margins, zero border, 1 pixel height and contrasting background color. 
This can be done by setting the style directly or by defining a class, for example, like:

```
.thin_hr {
margin-top:0;
margin-bottom:0;
border:0;
height:1px;
background-color:black;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
hr {
    display: block;
    height: 1px;
    border: 0;
    border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
    margin: 1em 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<div>Hello</div>
<hr/>
<div>World</div>
```

*emphasized text*

Comment: Please add a comment explaining your answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is relatively simple example and worked for me.

```
hr {
    width: 70%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

Resource: https://www.w3docs.com/snippets/css/how-to-style-a-horizontal-line.html

Answer (score 0):

A centered line, with a text in the middle, using margin-top and margin-bottom:

```css
.lineL {
  width: calc(32vw - 24px);
  margin-right:2vw;
  margin-bottom:5px;
  height: 0;
  border: 1px solid #a5a5a5;
  display:inline-block;
}
.lineR {
  width: calc(32vw - 24px);
  margin-left:2vw;
  margin-bottom:5px;
  height: 0;
  border: 1px solid #a5a5a5;
  display:inline-block;
}
.line {
  margin-bottom:40px;
  margin-top:20px;
  margin-left:auto;
  margin-right:auto;
  width:calc(70vw - 24px);
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>
  <button>Login</button>
  <div class="line">
    <div class="lineL"></div>
    <div style="display:inline-block;width:24px;">OR</div>
    <div class="lineR"></div>
  </div>
  <button>Logout</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

it is depends on requirement , but many developers suggestions is to make your code as **simple as possible** .
so, go with simple    "hr" tag
and CSS code for that.