# Horizontal line <hr /> with variable dash length

Tags: html, css

[Horizontal line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HyueS.png)

how to create the horizontal line with dash length as shown in image using CSS.
This is what i've tried

**CSS**

```
hr{
border-bottom: 1px dotted grey;
}
```

but i am unable get the same stroke length as shown in the image.

Comment: what is your effort? Or you want we do your homework?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [horizontal line and right way to code it in html, css](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14821087/horizontal-line-and-right-way-to-code-it-in-html-css)

Answer (score 1):

Try the below code: Use `border` css property.

```css
hr{
    border: 1px dashed #ccc;
}
```

```html
<p> hello </p>
<hr/>
```

Comment: i've used the same code but,i need the dash length to be large.

Comment: @Raviteja,  go through this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2771171/control-the-dashed-border-stroke-length-and-distance-between-strokes

Answer (score -1):

try border-bottom : 1px dashed;

This is such an easy *"google search"*. Do some work before you come and ask questions.

Comment: i've already done my work @Chaze and unable to get the dash length like that