# Horizontal Line Inside a Tab in HTML

Tags: html, css

I'm following these pages to create a horizontal line :
[horizontal line and right way to code it in html, css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14821087/horizontal-line-and-right-way-to-code-it-in-html-css)

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_hr.asp

http://www.jacklmoore.com/notes/jquery-tabs/

but It seems that It doesn't work inside my tab element. Here is my code :

```
 <div class="container-fluid">
         <div class="tabbable js-report-tab-container">
            <div class="tab-content">
            <div class="tab-pane active" id="tab1">
                <div id="circle"></div> <div class="h_line"> **<!-- horizontal line should be here -->**</div> <span id="circle"></span>
                 <br/><br/>
                 <p>Choose one of these type of reports : </p>
                   <input type="checkbox" name="report" value="reportValue" checked > Summary <br/>
                   <input type="checkbox" name="report" value="reportValue" > Candidate Details <br/>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="report" value="reportValue" > . . . .
               </div>
                 <div class="tab-pane" id="tab2">
                      This is the second step view...
                  </div>
                  <div class="tab-pane" id="tab3">
                      This is the third step view...
                    </div>
                   <div class="tab-pane" id="tab4">
                     This is the fourth step view...
                     </div>
                    </div> {{-- end of tab-content --}}
                    </div> {{-- end of tabbable --}}
        </div>
<style type="text/css">   
#circle {
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    background: blue;
    -moz-border-radius: 20px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 20px;
    border-radius: 20px;
     float: left;
}

.hline {
    width:100%;
    height:13px;
    background: #ff0000;
    clear:both;
    display:inline;
}

hr{
    display:inline;
    margin-top: 0.5em;
    border-width: 0.5px;
    border-style: inset;
    margin-bottom: 0.5em;

    height:2px;
    background: #00FF00;
    width: 20%;
    align:left;

</style>
```

I have tried to use `<hr align="left" />` and with css style :

```
hr{
    display:block;
    margin-top: 2.5em;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-style: inset;
    margin-bottom: 0.5em;
    border-top:1px solid;
    height:2px;
    background: #00FF00;
    width: 20%;
    align:left;
}
```

the result is like this :
[image]

I also tried to use `<div class="block_1">Lorem</div> <div class="h_line"></div>`
css : `.hline { width:30%; height:13px; background: #fff }`
Result is nothing :
[image]

Is there something I missed here...?? My goal is to create a horizontal between those 2 circles..

Thanks in advance... Need heelp here.. :)

Comment: Show all code after you change?

Comment: I just change  the <hr /> or <div class="h_line"></div> and applied css style, but there is no change...mmm.... I didn't change another code mr. @kollein

Comment: set .h_line css: width:100%;clear:both;

Comment: There is nothing change with width:100% and clearh:both; mr. Kollin... :')

Comment: The display: block is causing the hr to be on its own line. Try display: inline.

Comment: Kind of need to see full CSS, not just an hr clipping. It's pretty difficult to just *guess* at a page's CSS.

Comment: I changed display: to inline, but still no change mr. @ventaur

Comment: Oooowh... mmm... okie.. let me edit my question then Mr. @scott

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not entirely clear on what you're looking for, but here is one method of rendering a horizontal line between numbered circles. I've used something like this for a progress indicator in the past.

```css
.circles {
  border-bottom: 10px solid #000;
  display: block;
  height: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 15px auto;
  position: relative;
  width: 80%;
}

.circle {
  background: #00f;
  border-radius: 50%;
  color: #fff;
  height: 40px;
  line-height: 40px;
  margin: -20px 0 0 -20px;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  top: 5px;
  width: 40px;
}

.circle:nth-child(1) {
  left: 0;
}

.circle:nth-child(2) {
  left: 50%;
}

.circle:nth-child(3) {
  left: 100%;
}
```

```html
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
<ul class="circles">
  <li class="circle">1</li>
  <li class="circle">2</li>
  <li class="circle">3</li>
</ul>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
```

Comment: ooowh.. btw.... What is nth-child Mr. Brandon...?? I just met that style...it seems separating the space between circle 1, 2, 3, 4, buut..mmm... Is there any special thing about nth-child ? for example can I use it in another element like div, button or checkbox..?? :)

Comment: @HyosokaPoipo: Yes, you can use `:nth-child(n)` on any element. https://www.google.com/#q=nth-child

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using Bootstrap's columns to do something like this:

```
<div class="row">
     <div class="col-md-2"><div class="circle"></div></div>
     <div class="col-md-8"><hr /></div>
     <div class="col-md-2"><div class="circle"></div></div>
</div>
```

Comment: The circle is seperated far, but there is no horizontal line between them... :')