# How to insert divider in the `ngFor` in Angular?

Tags: angular, divider, angular-ngfor

I have a subsection and I'm wondering how I can place `html` divider between every subsection but not sure how to do that so I would be really appreciated if I can get any suggestion or help.

```html
<div>
    <a mat-list-item *ngFor="let subsection of section.subSections" (click)="navigateToSubsection(section.id,subsection.id)">{{subsection.sectionName}}
    </a>
</div>
```

For example something like this:

[image]

Comment: have you tried <a mat-list-item *ngFor="let subsection of section.subSections">{{subsection.sectionName}}<hr />
  </a> ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [horizontal line and right way to code it in html, css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14821087/horizontal-line-and-right-way-to-code-it-in-html-css)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use `<hr>` tag to render horizontal lines and `*ngFor` directive's [`last`](https://angular.io/api/common/NgForOf#local-variables) local variable to avoid rendering the line after the last item.

Try the following

```html
<div>
  <a *ngFor="let subsection of section.subSections; let last=last"
    (click)="navigateToSubsection(section.id,subsection.id)">
    {{ subsection.sectionName }}
    <hr *ngIf="!last" class="solid">
  </a>
</div>
```

Working example: [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-qeqxgu?file=src/app/app.component.html)

Answer (score 2):

I created a sample for you on [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ppvmgm?file=src/app/app.component.html)

You can use `<hr>` like this:

```html
<div clas="main-container" *ngFor="let subsection of section.subSections>
   <a mat-list-item"
    (click)="navigateToSubsection(section.id,subsection.id)">{{subsection.sectionName}}
   </a>
   <hr/>
</div>
```